# How to play sound in Java if I know the exact format of the audio file and need to play it repeatedly?

Tags: java, audio

I know there is [this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioInputStream(javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat,%20javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream)) but the documentation says that the file will be converted to the target format. I don't want to convert anything nor do I want the JRE to "try" and determine the audio format each time the audio file is played. How can I play audio file without this overhead? By the way, the file is a `.wav`.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried sometime back. Sound format was .wav

You may try once...

```
public static synchronized void audioPlay(String fileLoc) {new Thread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
      try {
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        AudioInputStream ais= AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
          Main.class.getResourceAsStream("the path of the wav file" + fileLoc));
        clip.open(ais);
        clip.start(); 
      } 
catch (Exception ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
       System.out.println(ex.getMessage);
      }
    }
  }).start();
}
```

Comment: Yes, my application already plays the file like this. The documentation of "getAudioInputStream(...)" method you are using says "The implementation of this method may require multiple parsers to examine the stream to determine whether they support it." I know the exact format of the audio file so I would not like any parsers to  "try" to determine the format.

Comment: So, I think my answer helps you. Does it ?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here: http://www.albeesonline.com/blog/2007/10/20/play-wav-files-using-java/

```
try {
    AudioInputStream stream =
    AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("C:\\i386\\Blip.wav"));

    AudioFormat format = stream.getFormat();
    DataLine.Info info =
              new DataLine.Info(Clip.class,format);
    Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);

    clip.open(stream);
    clip.start();

  } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Now I can save format for later use.